# Same site in two folders different CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, server

I have my created in the server and folder: `mywebsite.com/folder1`
I want to have the same website (functionalities), but changing some images and css font. I am thinking about creating a new folder `mywebsite.com/folder2` and copy the files from folder1 to folder2 and just replace the CSS and images that I need.

This solution looks not good because I'll have a lot of html and js files duplicated in my server. Is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to use folder1 contents in the files in folder2. Let's start with this: HTML accepts some Linux properties. For example:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../folder1/styleInFolder1.css">`

As you see, you can use `../`. HTML searchs all ancestral files until it find styleInFolder1 out.

Additionally, CSS accepts the same thing in a different way. When you add that line to very top of your new CSS file:

`@import "../styleInFolder1.css"`

new file takes all features in the styleInFolder1, you can add any line to your new CSS file. It will work for only the new file. You can change your font type etc.

I hope these will be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the reusable parts in individual files and include them via [phps include](http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php).
The other parts around, as well as the CSS can be included seperately.

This way, you only have to maintain the core elements in one place, while having the ability to change style in other places.